# Docker ENTRYPOINT variable not carried forward into CMD

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a base image which exports a number of variables in it's ENTRYPOINT shell script docker-entry.sh.

Now I'm consuming the base image and running CMD with a mongo-entry.sh. I was hoping to access the variables exported from the ENTRYPOINT in the mongo-entry.sh.

I'm able to see the the log statements with the variables from docker-entry.sh being printed out, but, I'm unable to access it in mongo-entry.sh

I've already tried calling the docker-entry.sh and mongo-entry.sh as ENTRYPOINT in my DockerFile

Code:

Base Image ENTRYPOINT docker-entry.sh

```
 export var1 = "var1"
```

Current image

```
FROM 'baseimage'
COPY ["mongo-entry.sh"]
CMD ["mongo-entry.sh"]
```

mongo-entry.sh

```
echo "var1=$VAR1"
```

Ouptut

```
var1=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect there are 1-2 issues:

1. `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` aren't inherited from the `FROM` image
2. You may be using the exec form of `ENTRYPOINT`|`CMD`

There are 2 forms of `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`, the shell and exec forms. The exec form "does not invoke a command shell" and so you won't get environment variable processing:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Here's an example which shows `ENV` values passing through `FROM`'d images:

```sh
echo '
FROM bash
ENV DOG=Freddie
ENTRYPOINT echo "dog=${DOG}"
' | docker build --tag=1st --file=- .
```

```sh
echo '
FROM 1st
ENV CAT=Emmett
ENTRYPOINT echo "dog=${DOG}" "cat=${CAT}"
' | docker build --tag=2nd --file=- .
```

```sh
docker run 1st
docker run 2nd
```

Results in:

```
dog=Freddie
dog=Freddie cat=Emmett
```

**NB** `${DOG}` (and its value) is inherited from `1st`

Comment: You're right... 

Base Image ENTRYPOINT

` export var1 = "var1"`

Current image

```
FROM 'baseimage'
COPY ["custom.sh"]
CMD ["custom.sh"]
```

custom.sh
```
echo $VAR1
```

Ouptut

Comment: I was running it in exec mode and it spawned off a different process.